# append new observables to array of observables?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I am trying to avoid the following:

```
switchMap(([action, state]) =>
  from(TodosDB.getAll()).pipe(
    map(
      (todos) => onQueryTodoDone({ items: todos }),
      catchError((err) => of(onQueryTodoFail({ error: err })))
    )
  )
),
```

to something more linear like like we do with combineLatestFrom in ngrx.
So far I tried to do the below. But the promise does not seem to work.

```
withLatestFrom(
  from(TodosDB.getAll())
),
```

and

```
withLatestFrom(
  from(TodosDB.getAll()).pipe(
    map((todos) => onQueryTodoDone({ items: todos }))
  )
)
```

Any ideas how to deal with this scenario without nesting pipe map in a switchMap?

PS: this might be obvious to you but I don't know much and I looked up on the internet and found withLatestFrom but not sure what I am missing.

EDIT: this is the best I got so far:

```
switchMap(([action, state]) =>
  forkJoin([of(action), of(state), TodosDB.getAll()])
),
map(
  ([action, state, todos]) => onQueryTodoDone({ items: todos }),
  catchError((err) => of(onQueryTodoFail({ error: err })))
),
```

The above is better but I have no idea if that can cause issues later. But hopefully I was able to communicate the idea. Which is append a promise result to the piped observable keep it's original structure

```
[Observable<Actions>,Observable<State>,Observable<FromPromise>]
```

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for `combineAll()` but I'm not sure what's your usecase

Comment: no, did not work either. I updated the question with a step closer. basically the idea is to get a promise result from within a pipe but keep the previous observables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joining a few dots here and taking a bit of a guess I would say the problem stems from `TodosDB.getAll` returning a `Promise`.

With a promise based function you want to lazily evaluate it, as such a function is executed *immediately* when it is called, unlike an observable based function which requires a subscription.

This is why the `switchMap` based solutions work, because the body of the `switchMap` is not evaluated until the source emits.

In your shortened version using `withLatestFrom`, there is no lazy evaluation, the `getAll` call is probably evaluated once and once only when the effect is set up.

You can use the `defer` operator to convert your promise based function to one that behaves more appropriately with the rxjs observable based operators.

```
withLatestFrom(defer(() => this.getAll())),  // use of defer
map(([[action, state], todos]) => [action, state, todos]),  // refine the shape of the data to your requirements
...
```

**Stackblitz:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qkwqyw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Note: The `concatLatestFrom` ngrx operator also looks like it may be of use but I couldn't get it to work how I wanted.

Comment: your answer works, but there is a weird behavior in my code that if i dispatch a manual action after the store is started it works normally, but since I am listening for the "nrgx store init action" (a clue I probably should not do that) it call the function but nothing changes. But regardless it works, thanks